# Hamiltonian formulation of general relativity in ADM formalism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, hamiltonian-formalism, adm-formalism

I'm working on ADM formalism, and this is part of my Hamiltonian

$$H_{2}=2 \int d^3 x \quad p^{a b}D_{a}N_{b} = 2 \int d^3 x \quad p^{ab}h_{bc}(\partial_a N^{c}+\Gamma^{c}_{ab}N^{d}).$$

I need to find

$$\frac{\delta H_{2}}{\delta h_{ab}} = 2 p^{c(a}D_{c}N^{b)} - \sqrt{det \quad h} D_{c}(p^{ab}N^{c}/\sqrt{det \quad h}).$$

Where: $h_{ab}$ is the metric of space-time, $$p^{ab}=\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \dot{h}_{ab}}$$ and $$ds^{2} = -N^{2}dt^{2}+h_{ab}(dx^{a}+N^{a}dt)(dx^{b}+N^{b}dt).$$

I have no idea how I find $\frac{\delta H_{2}}{\delta h_{ab}}$.

Comment: Hi Kamog. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to derive the dynamical equations for the ADM formalism then you may want to follow the treatment in [Wald's text](https://www.amazon.ca/General-Relativity-Robert-M-Wald/dp/0226870332). There in Appendix E.2 you will see your $H_2$ written as a boundary term plus another term (this is by product rule):

Let $H_2=\int_{\Sigma_t} \mathcal{H}_2 $, then, $\mathcal{H}_2=2h^{1/2}\left\{-N_b[D_a(h^{-1/2} p^{ab})]+D_a(h^{-1/2}N_bp^{ab})\right\}$. Now the $D_a(h^{-1/2}N_bp^{ab})$ part can be dropped since it is a boundary term.

Comment: Wald is unclear to me in E.2.36. Look, I need to derive $ 2 p^{c(a}D_{c}N^{b)} - \sqrt{det \quad h} D_{c}(p^{ab}N^{c}/\sqrt{det \quad h})$, from $H_{2}=2 \int d^3 x \quad p^{a b}D_{a}N_{b} = 2 \int d^3 x \quad p^{ab}h_{bc}(\partial_a N^{c}+\Gamma^{c}_{ab}N^{d})$. I'm very newbie in TRG (i'm learning it), so I did it:

$\frac{\delta H_{2}}{\delta h_{ab}}= \int d^{3}x \ \left(p^{ab}\frac{\delta h_{bc}}{\delta h_{bc}}(\partial_{a}N^{c}+\Gamma^{c}_{ab}N^{d}) + p^{ab}h_{bc}\frac{\delta}{\delta h_{ab}}(\partial_{a}N^{c}+\Gamma^{c}_{ab}N^{d}) \right)$

But it looks wrong!

Comment: I should have:

$\frac{\delta H_{2}}{\delta h_{ab}}=2 p^{(a |c|}D_{c}N^{b)}+2\int d^3x \ p^{cd}h_{de}\frac{\Gamma^{e}_{cf}}{\delta h_{ab}}N^{f}$.

But I can't obtain the first term...

Comment: @Kamog The indices $ab$ in $\delta/\delta h_{ab}$ are not dummy indices. One thing that will help is to avoid using the same indices as dummy indices in the expression that you're varying.